# Modifying workflow to add a status and split on ticket type

Tags: trac

I am hoping that someone can help me as I am completely lost. I need to modify the workflow for TRAC so that if the ticket type is SPR, it gets assigned to our QA, and they are the only ones allowed closing the ticket. Otherwise, it goes to the test team to be closed.

As well, I need the ticket status flow to be as follows:

New Ticket(bug) -> Assigned(Dev) -> Fixed(re-assigned to Test or SPR) -> Closed/Re-opened

Currently it appears the ticket is set to closed after dev fixes the issue.

I am not familliar with TRAC at all and have been hammering away at this for 2 days now and can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try [AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin), because it is able to act differently based on ticket field values. Most relevant here: It does so with *triage* operation based on ticket type according to its wiki documentation:

```
accept = new -> *
accept.name = Accept ticket into workflow
accept.operations = triage
accept.triage_field = type
accept.triage_split = defect->new_defect,enhancement->new_enhancement
```

(see a more complete example on the wiki page linked above)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the status workflow of your tickets (this is the official documentation: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWorkflow). However, different workflows based on ticket type are not yet supported.